# Union of span of two vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

i have problems solving this question:

These are vectors of standard vector space $V = \mathbb{R}^{4}$:

$v_{1}=(1,1,1,1),v_{2}=(4,4,0,0),v_{3}=(3,4,2,1),v_{4}=(2,3,1,1),v_{5}=(1,0,0,0)$

1) I have to show that $span\{v_{1}\} \cup span\{v_{2}\}$ is no subspace of $V$.

2) I have to show that $span\{v_{1},v_{5},v_{5}\} \cup span\{v_{2}\}$ is a subspace of $V$.

I haven't worked with spans and vectors yet.

Do you have a hint for me? How can i start? Maybe something with linear combinations?!? What is the span of a vector?

Comment: Asking `What is the span of a vector?` implies lack of yourself research, so take a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange!  You say you "haven't worked with spans and vectors yet".  If you haven't worked with vectors where in the world did you get this question?  Are you taking a linear algebra class?

In any case, seeing that this problem talks about the "span" of a vector, I would think that the first thing you would do is look up the definition of "span".  The "span" of a set of vectors is the set of all possible *linear combinations* of those vectors.

In particular the span of a single vector is the set of all multiples of that vector.   The span of vector $v_1= (1, 1, 1, 1)$ is all vectors of the form (a, a, a, a) where a is any number.  The span of vector $v_2= (4, 4, 0, 0)$ is all numbers of the form (4b, 4b, 0, 0) where b is any number.  The union of those two spans is any vector that can be written in **either** of those forms.  In particular, (1, 1, 1, 1) and (4, 4, 0, 0) themselves are in that union.  If this were a subspace, then their sum, (1, 1, 1, 1)+ (4, 4, 0, 0)= (5, 5, 1, 1) would be in that set.  But (5, 5, 1, 1) is neither of the form (a, a, a, a) nor of the form (4b, 4b, 0, 0) so is not in that set.

Comment: ok thank you very much. yes i am taking a linear algebra class. i will try to understand the span definition.